# How to skip a row in Java when asserting text

Tags: java, parsing, assert

I have the following .txt file:

```
Fuzzy search: 
A line of text I would like to skip.
YES
Other text...
```

How can I assert that the file contains "Fuzzy search" and "YES" two lines below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach:

- you read the file line by line (and remember the line number)
- when you hit "Fuzzy search:", you remember the line where you found it
- when you hit "YES" ... you check if you had a "Fuzzy search" hit, and if so, you check corresponding line number

( as you didn't show any code of yourself, I assume you are merely looking for guidance, which ... you got here. If you need more details, consider adding more details to your question )

Comment: Thanks, I think this could be enough. Will try it out later.

Comment: Note that you can do this in a million ways, but regular expression will likely be the easiest...

Comment: @TylerNichols I disagree. What is easier than `line.startsWith("Fuzzy search")` for one case, and `line.startsWith("YES")` for the other. Sure, if things are more complicated, then a regular expression might be helpful. But to determine that a line starts with a certain string ... regexes are overkill. (and of course: a simple startswith is also way cheaper to compute)

Comment: @TylerNichols What would be the regex to do this?